# Is there a Spanish word or phrase for the term "voice inside my head?"

Tags: vocabulario

just out of curiosity I'm looking to see if there's a way in Spanish to describe what us English speakers refer to as the "voice in my head," a.k.a your subconscious, devil on your shoulder, guilt, etc. (Bonus points for a more colliqualy friendly word or phrase too! Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

En español tenemos varias maneras de expresar "**La voz dentro de la cabeza**" o "**Voz de la Cabeza**".

Puede recibir el nombre de **Voz interior**, **Voz de la Conciencia**, **Voz Mental**, **Voz Diegética**, incluso **Voz Espiritual**  o **Dialogo Interno**. Se trata de una voz con la que solemos hablar o conversar y que representa los pensamientos de la persona.

Se trata de un autodiálogo que nace de la profundidad de nuestras creencias, una manera de comunicarnos con nosotros mismos y que puede impactar tanto de forma positiva como negativamente en nuestra autoestima.

Por otro lado tener "**Voces en la Cabeza**" en plural, es un síntoma que padecen muchos pacientes con esquizofrenia.